# How to rectify the conflicts which occur at concurrent transactions in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have the `function` which `checks` the `maximum value` of pid and then `inserts` into the database.

But it raises a `conflict` while i have `concurrent transactions!`

So how can i avoid this conflict!

```
create table tablea(
  sno serial,
  pid integer,
  ppid integer,
  pname text
  );
```

--This is the function checks the maximum value of pid and then inserts into the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_details(_pname text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    _pid int;
begin
   _pid := (select MAX(pid) from tablea);
   _pid := coalesce(_pid, 0) + 1;

   insert into tablea(pid,pname)
   values(_pid,_pname);
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

--(Sub Party)This is the function checks the maximum value of ppid and then inserts into the database.(sub-Party)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_details(_pid int,_pname text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
        _ppid int;
begin
   _ppid := (select MAX(ppid) from tablea where pid=_pid);
   _ppid := coalesce(_ppid, 0) + 1;

   insert into tablea(pid,ppid,pname)
   values (_pid,_ppid,_pname);
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

**My Requirement** : When i hit a `submit` button from the front end then my `field(pname)` should be inserted into the `tablea`,by incrementing the `pid by +1`, so i cant remove my pid from the tablea,and pid is kept integer so that i can insert another record by the same pid & the flow is as same as with ppid too..

So should i change my table structure or else any other way to rectify the conflicts in concurrent transactions.

This is How my Whole concept is all about 
[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/36381/1)

Comment: I am using java Primefaces as my User Interface with Springs and hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

On way to avoid conflicts permanently and effectively would be to **drop the redundant `pid`** from your table. Use `sno` instead for all purposes. And disallow direct input for the column, so that the default from the attached sequence cannot be circumvented. `sno` can have gaps, that's by design. But it works flawlessly for a unique column under concurrent load. And later requests (starting later) get a higher serial number. That's what a `serial` column is good for.

If you really need a gapless "pid", you can emulate one with `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sno) AS pid FROM tablea
```

Now, the synthesized `pid` is not stable if rows can be deleted. But what's the point of this exercise if there can be gaps in the numbering after all?

Comment: i edited the question with my requirement so could u please help me to proceed further

Comment: i'm using the sno as a composite primary key for both pid and ppid, and the pid is the party_id and ppid is the sub party which i keeo under any pid... the edited fiddle is in below..in my requirement @Erwin Brandstetter

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to reduce chance of conflict:

```
insert into tablea(pid,pname)
values(coalesce((select MAX(pid) from tablea), 0) + 1,_pname);
```

To avoid conflict completely you can also set [transaction isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) to serializable (read about it first to consider pros and cons):

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;

insert into tablea(pid,pname)
values(coalesce((select MAX(pid) from tablea), 0) + 1,_pname);
```

Comment: i'm using the sno as a composite primary key for both pid and ppid, and the pid is the party_id and ppid is the sub party which i keeo under any pid... the edited fiddle is in below..in my requirement